# Events or operations in gmail add ins

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I'm trying to create a Gmail web add-in using apps-script in which I am trying to do the following things:

> 1. make an API call on receiving an email.
> 2. label emails.
> 3. move emails to
> 4. spam. get all emails of a specific folder.

Is this possible? If Yes then how? Please give me the links to any documentation or tutorials for the same.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is *sort of* possible, but you should be aware that Gmail Add-ons can be triggered either by *opening an email* or *opening compose Ui* both by explicit user interaction with Gmail, not when an email is recieved (though, Gmail Add-ons platform is growing and this trigger can be added in the near future).

As for the actions 2-4, they are entirely possible, you should take a look at the following references:

1. Gmail Add-ons [guide and reference](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/);
2. GitHub repo with [sample Add-ons](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/gmail-add-ons-samples) from Google;
3. [OAuth2.0 library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) for 3P service calls (if it authenticates via OAuth2.0);
4. `Gmail` [service reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/) for apps script.

This should definitely help you get started, happy coding!